# Need to use the smtp settings of coldfusion 10

Tags: coldfusion

There is a new settings of `Application.cfc` in the coldfusion 10 which is:

```
   this.smtpServersettings = as a structure
```

I can hard code the values here, but i am saving my mail settings in the database and i want to use those values here, is it possible or not to use the database settings here or not.

here is my Update:

```
<cfcomponent hint="File for the Website" output="false">
    <cfsetting showdebugoutput="no">
    <cfset this.name = "myProject1">
    <cfset this.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan(2,0,0,0)>
    <cfset this.clientmanagement= "yes">
    <cfset this.loginstorage = "session">
    <cfset this.sessionmanagement = "yes">
    <cfset this.sessiontimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,40,0) />
    <cfset this.setClientCookies = "yes">
    <cfset this.scriptProtect = "all">
    <cfset this.setDomainCookies = true>
    <cfset this.customTagPaths = ExpandPath('customtags')>
    <cfset this.datasource = {name="myDB"}>
    <cfset this.smtpServersettings = {structur as username,password and mail settings}>
```

but that value needs to be through database, can you show me an example please

Comment: It sounds like you would have to render the cfc from the database.

Comment: what exactly does mean that

Comment: Can you generate the cfc with a program that can read from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to set the value of the `this.smtpServersettings` variable from a database query. And for what it's worth, I think that setting as been available since ColdFusion 9.

All you would need to do is something like the following.

1. Run your query to get the values from the database
2. Create a new structure
3. Assign the three variables to that structure; server, username, and password
4. Assign the `this.smtpServersettings` variable to your new structure

Of course you will need to add some code to do something if/when your database query fails.

**Update after the question was updated**

Just do something like the following (pseudo code):

```
<cfcomponent hint="File for the Website" output="false">
    <cfsetting showdebugoutput="no">
    <cfset this.name = "myProject1">
    <cfset this.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan(2,0,0,0)>
    <cfset this.clientmanagement= "yes">
    <cfset this.loginstorage = "session">
    <cfset this.sessionmanagement = "yes">
    <cfset this.sessiontimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,40,0) />
    <cfset this.setClientCookies = "yes">
    <cfset this.scriptProtect = "all">
    <cfset this.setDomainCookies = true>
    <cfset this.customTagPaths = ExpandPath('customtags')>
    <cfset this.datasource = {name="myDB"}>

    <!--- run your query here --->
    <!--- check your query and do something appropriate if/when it fails --->
    <cfset this.MyStructure = StructNew()>
    <cfset this.MyStructure.server = this.MyQuery.ServerNameVariable>
    <cfset this.MyStructure.username = this.MyQuery.UserNameVariable>
    <cfset this.MyStructure.password = this.MyQuery.PasswordVariable>

    <cfset this.smtpServersettings = this.MyStructure>
```

You also need to be aware that doing it this way will run that query on *every* page request. Make sure it runs fast.

Comment: oh, can i but i had that `this.smtpServersettings` is defined in my `<cfcomponent>`, i will update my question, please check

Comment: The `this.smtpServersettings`setting will only work when defined in the Application.cfc file.

Comment: but the query is not in request scope, why it will run every time,

Comment: i can use cfinclude here right <!--- run your query here --->

Comment: It will run every time because this is in the initialization code of the Application.cfc file - it runs every time. You should be able to use cfinclude here as well. Be mindful of variable scopes!  As I said, this will run on every request.

Comment: can i use the includeonce attribute, how will that behave in this case

Comment: it is giving me an error: 
Variable MAILSTRUCTURE is undefined. the line pointing is this: <cfset this.smtpServersettings = mailStructure>

Comment: Did you declare the variable and assign it values before that statement? If you are having further issues please ask a new question as it will dilute this one which I think has already been answered.

Comment: i fixed it, but my question is open can i use runonce = true with cfinclude so it may not run again & again.

Comment: I don't think that will help. Runonce keeps it from being run again during the same request. What I am saying is that this code will run for each unique request. But you can try it.

Comment: `<cfset this.MyStructure = StructNew()>` - I would use the `variables` scope here, i.e., `<cfset variables.mystructure = structNew() />` (or `= {} />`)